# How can I make spring deliver an emitted Flux error to the client

Tags: spring-webflux

In a simple spring-webflux project using spring-boot `3.1.5` I have the following problem. I am using `Flux.create` and a sink to emit values through an SSE endpoint. When an exception occurs and is emitted **after the initial setup** the connection just breaks without delivering the specific exception to the client.

I would have expected the exception to be delivered to the client Flux.

I debugged it so far that the problem is that spring thinks the connection is already committed. I think this is only halve of the story since the exception could still be delivered through the open connection just like the other SSE messages.

`Error [java.lang.RuntimeException: Wifi cable not found 2023-11-08T07:45:36.574336976Z] for HTTP GET "/api/fail/hello-flux-later", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)`

Maybe this is not implemented or I am using it wrong. Maybe there is a way for me to implement it on my own.
I could add a try and catch all and incorporate an error field to all of my response objects but I would rather not. I would like a solution that works even if I do not handle the exception explicitly and where I do not have to wrap all response entities.

A generic solution might be to create a new SSE field like `error:`  which unfortunately is not specified by https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#event-stream-interpretation – maybe this is the reason why spring is also just aborting like that?

*(Side note: I am aware that the `Flux.create` method is not in a very reactive spirit but it is to bridge the two worlds and I do not see this as the topic of this question.)*

```java
public record SimpleResponse(String content) {}

@GetMapping(path = "hello-flux-later", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
Flux<SimpleResponse> helloFluxLater() {
    return Flux.create(sink -> {

        final Thread creator = new Thread(() -> {
            LOGGER.info("Starting hello flux thread, failing after 3");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                if (i == 3) {

                    // FIXME: not received by the subscriber
                    LOGGER.info("Sending {} error", i);
                    sink.error(new RuntimeException("Wifi cable not found " + Instant.now()));
                } else {

                    LOGGER.info("Sending {}", i);
                    sink.next(new SimpleResponse("hello " + Instant.now());
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    LOGGER.info("Interrupted at {}", i);
                    return;
                }
            }

            LOGGER.info("Sending done, finishing sink and thread");
            sink.complete();
        });
        creator.setDaemon(true);
        creator.start();

        sink.onDispose(() -> {
            LOGGER.info("Flux disposed, stopping thread");
            creator.interrupt();
        });
    });
}
```

Client side:

```
http -v --stream localhost:8080/api/fail/hello-flux-later                                                     
GET /api/fail/hello-flux-later HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.2.0



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

data:{"content":"hello 2023-11-08T07:45:33.568766666Z"}

data:{"content":"hello 2023-11-08T07:45:34.569467283Z"}

data:{"content":"hello 2023-11-08T07:45:35.573303790Z"}


http: error: ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))
```

Server side log:

```
2023-11-08T08:45:33.563+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [11a660e4, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] New http connection, requesting read
2023-11-08T08:45:33.563+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] r.netty.transport.TransportConfig        : [11a660e4, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2023-11-08T08:45:33.566+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [11a660e4, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] Increasing pending responses, now 1
2023-11-08T08:45:33.567+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [11a660e4-1, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@7ab3fac
2023-11-08T08:45:33.567+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [11a660e4-8] HTTP GET "/api/fail/hello-flux-later"
2023-11-08T08:45:33.567+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [11a660e4-8] Mapped to de.gsi.bpeter.experiment.springwebfluxplain.FailingController#helloFluxLater()
2023-11-08T08:45:33.568+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [11a660e4-8] Using 'text/event-stream' given [*/*] and supported [text/event-stream]
2023-11-08T08:45:33.568+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [11a660e4-8] 0..N [de.gsi.bpeter.experiment.springwebfluxplain.SimpleResponse]
2023-11-08T08:45:33.568+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty               : [11a660e4-1, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] Non Removed handler: reactor.left.readTimeoutHandler, context: null, pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2023-11-08T08:45:33.568+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Starting hello flux thread, failing after 3
2023-11-08T08:45:33.568+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Sending 0
2023-11-08T08:45:33.568+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SimpleResponse                 : Creating response SimpleResponse[content=hello 2023-11-08T07:45:33.568766666Z]
2023-11-08T08:45:33.569+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [11a660e4-8] Encoding [SimpleResponse[content=hello 2023-11-08T07:45:33.568766666Z]]
2023-11-08T08:45:34.569+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Sending 1
2023-11-08T08:45:34.569+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SimpleResponse                 : Creating response SimpleResponse[content=hello 2023-11-08T07:45:34.569467283Z]
2023-11-08T08:45:34.569+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [      Thread-15] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [11a660e4-8] Encoding [SimpleResponse[content=hello 2023-11-08T07:45:34.569467283Z]]
2023-11-08T08:45:35.573+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Sending 2
2023-11-08T08:45:35.573+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SimpleResponse                 : Creating response SimpleResponse[content=hello 2023-11-08T07:45:35.573303790Z]
2023-11-08T08:45:35.573+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [      Thread-15] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [11a660e4-8] Encoding [SimpleResponse[content=hello 2023-11-08T07:45:35.573303790Z]]
2023-11-08T08:45:36.574+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Sending 3 error
2023-11-08T08:45:36.574+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SimpleResponse                 : Creating exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Wifi cable not found 2023-11-08T07:45:36.574336976Z
2023-11-08T08:45:36.574+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Flux disposed, stopping thread
2023-11-08T08:45:36.574+01:00  INFO 10893 --- [      Thread-15] d.g.b.e.s.SpringWebfluxPlainService      : Interrupted at 3
2023-11-08T08:45:36.574+01:00 ERROR 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [11a660e4-8] Error [java.lang.RuntimeException: Wifi cable not found 2023-11-08T07:45:36.574336976Z] for HTTP GET "/api/fail/hello-flux-later", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)
2023-11-08T08:45:36.575+01:00 ERROR 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [11a660e4-1, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] Error finishing response. Closing connection

java.lang.RuntimeException: Wifi cable not found 2023-11-08T07:45:36.574336976Z
    at de.gsi.bpeter.experiment.springwebfluxplain.SimpleResponse.createException(SimpleResponse.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler de.gsi.bpeter.experiment.springwebfluxplain.FailingController#helloFluxLater() [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/fail/hello-flux-later" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at de.gsi.bpeter.experiment.springwebfluxplain.SimpleResponse.createException(SimpleResponse.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
        at de.gsi.bpeter.experiment.springwebfluxplain.FailingController.lambda$2(FailingController.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-11-08T08:45:36.575+01:00 DEBUG 10893 --- [or-http-epoll-9] r.netty.channel.ChannelOperations        : [11a660e4-1, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:8080 ! R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0]:44362] [HttpServer] Channel inbound receiver cancelled (channel disconnected).
```

Complete example: https://github.com/dedeibel/spring-webflux-sse-flux-error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be no other solution besides moving the problem to the application level and using a "response" object that can handle both, values or errors.

Here is some code that worked in test setup but is not pretty to me.

```java
// Error response object
public record WebExposedServiceExceptionResponse(String type, String message) {}

// Value or error wrapper
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
public record WebValueOrError<T>(T value, WebExposedServiceExceptionResponse error) {
    public boolean representsError() { return error != null; }
    public boolean empty() { return false; }
}

// In the webflux REST controller

@GetMapping(value = "/mystream" , produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<WebValueOrError<PayloadPojo>>> mystream() {

    return myService.createMyStream() // Returns some Flux<PayloadPojo> that might emit an error
            .map(payload -> ServerSentEvent.builder(new WebValueOrError<>(payload, null)).build()) // Good case
            .onErrorResume( // Error case, only executed once
                    error -> Mono.just(
                            ServerSentEvent.builder(
                                new WebValueOrError<>(
                                    (PayloadPojo) null,
                                    new WebExposedServiceExceptionResponse(
                                        error.getClass().getSimpleName(), error.getMessage())))
                            .build()));
}


// When observed using curl or http

/*

data:{"value":{"gross":9001,"category":"overninethousand"}}

data:{"error":{"type":"RuntimeException","message":"Provoked error"}}

*/

// Client side example impl

Flux<PayloadPojo> payloads = client.getWebClient()
    .get()
    .uri("/mystream")
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<WebValueOrError<PayloadPojo>>>() {})
    .flatMap((final ServerSentEvent<WebValueOrError<PayloadPojo>> event) -> {
        if (event.data() == null || event.data().empty()) {
            return Mono.empty(); // flux completed
        } else if (event.data().representsError()) {
            final WebExposedServiceExceptionResponse error = event.data().error();
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Connection error: " + error.type() + " message: " + error.message()));
        } else {
            return Mono.just(event.data().value());
        }
    });
```